# How to get the value on change of the spinner in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

why doesn't fragment support spinners in it? I have the following fragment class and added spinners to it.

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {
Spinner spinner1;
public List<String> genderitems, titleitems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settinglayout, container,
            false);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.usertitle);

    titleitems = new ArrayList<String>();

    setTitleSpinnerContent(rootview);

    titleitems.add("Beginner");
    titleitems.add("Novice");

    return rootview;

}

private void setTitleSpinnerContent(View view) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, titleitems);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adp);
}}
```

How to get the spinner change value upon selection and add it a textview on the spinner.
What is that i am missing here? Thanks in advance.

I tried even adding onitemselectedlistener() but too the result is nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no differences in adding spinners in `activity` and `fragment`. If u want to get the spinner item changed `listener` implement like this..

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) { 

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),  
            "On Item Select : \n" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 

    @Override 
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    } 
}
```

Comment: No its not the same, I am not getting any result !!

Comment: I updated it and that is what after it is the result

Comment: Did the spinner contents are populated or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what your specific problem is, but if the problem is that you aren't seeing your spinner populated with the values 'Beginner' and 'Novice', it looks like have set your adapter on the empty list, and then added items to the list after the adapter is set.  But you never called notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter, so it doesn't know about your new values.  Have you tried the simple solution of adding the items to your list before you set the adapter?

```
    titleitems.add("Beginner");
    titleitems.add("Novice");
    setTitleSpinnerContent(rootview);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Laura , but the above 1 worked for me .